# Finding all nodes not referenced by a menu entry or another node

Tags: nodes

In the course of creating the content for a site, we've ended up with orphaned content nodes that are not linked to from anywhere. I'd like to find and examine these. Surprisingly, I can't find a module for this.

Tiny hypothetical example: I'm building a brochureware site. Someone wrote a "Contact" page, someone else wrote an "About Us", and someone else wrote "Directions". The person writing "Directions" forgot to put it in a menu link or add a link from "About Us" to "Directions". So "Directions" is orphaned: there are no links to it. I'd like to find all such nodes so I can figure out what to do with them.

Comment: Are you seeing this nodes when you are listing al nodes?

Comment: Yes. There's nothing special about them. They just happen to be orphaned in terms of menus and links.

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot delete them from the from the general content page?

Comment: No, but that's not the issue. Of, say, all the Basic Pages on the content page, I want to know which ones are orphans and which ones are not. I'm going to look at the orphans and see if there's some content inside I want. If not, I'll delete them. The issue is that I can't tell which ones are orphans just by looking at the list. For instance, one of my editors may have written, say, a "Contacts" page, but we forgot to put it in a menu and so it's currently inaccessible unless you know the URL.

Comment: Are you just interested in existing modules, or would you be willing to write a custom module if no module does what you are looking for?

Comment: This is a small task right now, so I wouldn't write a module, though I know how. Just thought someone might have already done the work.  By the way, I edited the question back to a more general one. I'm not quite sure why this has required so much explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For links from the menu system:**

[Menu Node Views](https://drupal.org/project/menu_node_views) comes very close to what you request but needs [some coding](http://drupal.org/node/1451940).

**For links from the body (fields) of nodes:**

The Search module saves references between nodes. This can be used by views to create a "backlinks" view. For Drupal 5 there was a [seperate module for this](https://drupal.org/project/backlinks) with some aditional explenation, since D6 (Views 2/3) this functionallity is baked into Views Module.

**Summary**

[views](https://drupal.org/project/views) + [vbo](https://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) + [Menu Node API](https://drupal.org/project/menu_node) + [Menu Node Views](https://drupal.org/project/menu_node_views) ( + custom filter/patch or [View with custom query](https://drupal.org/node/409808) )

Comment: This is helpful, though it doesn't handle links to nodes from the body (or whatever) of other nodes. I think it's as good as I'm going to get - thanks.

Comment: Oops, missed that part. Added the missing information now.

Answer (score 5):

I needed this for a clients request, so i decided to try and do it without any additional modules, and push my MySQL a bit. This is what i ended up with.

For clarity, this will only provide a list of NID's that DO NOT have an associated menu item.

I've also added a WHERE clause to limit content types, as some content types will naturally be excluded because of the way they was architected.

```
SELECT n.nid, n.type, n.title, n.status
FROM node AS n
WHERE (n.type = 'article' OR n.type = 'page')
AND n.nid NOT IN (
  SELECT REPLACE(link_path, "node/", "") AS nid
  FROM menu_links
  WHERE SUBSTRING(link_path, 6, LENGTH(link_path)) REGEXP "^[0-9]+$" 
);
```

Comment: Nice solution! +1 for no new modules.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views)? You'll need to create a view for the orphaned nodes, which would depend on your taxonomy and fields.

Comment: I'm looking for, say, Basic Page nodes that have no menu entry or are not linked to from any other node. They have no taxonomy. There's no View query that's going to find these.

Comment: I was under the impression that you could use (not) logic on Views. So you could say something like Nodes where xyz taxonomy field is empty.

Comment: These nodes have no taxonomy fields. I just want to know if they are accessible in a menu or if they are linked to from the content of some other (accessible) node.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish the menu portion pretty easily with a custom query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM node
WHERE node.type = 'page'
AND node.nid NOT IN (
 SELECT nid
 FROM menu_node
)
```